# Mysql concat column on table while joining from another to php

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the basic layout:

```
Table1:
    id 10, blah
    id 11, test
Table2: 
    id 1, 10, some info
    id 2, 10, more info
    id 3, 11, more info
```

What query using sql would allow me to display the results like so, when using php and mysql_fetch_object:

```
10, blah, more info, some info
11, test, more info
```

Right now, I have:

```
select * from table1
join (table2, table3)
on (table2.id = table1.id and table3.id = table1.id)
```

The problem with this is that I get multiple result rows for the same id because of the multiple values in tables 2 and 3.

**EDIT: I got it to work!**

```
select table1.id, group_concat(table2.data), table3.data
from table1
join (table2, table3)
on (table2.id = table1.id and table3.id = table1.id)
group by table1.id
```

Comment: use group_concat(), example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894584/need-to-concatenate-results-of-a-subquery-in-a-select-statement/3894671#3894671

Comment: I got it to work as I needed from that example. Thanks!!
The key point was to group_concat the column with multiple entries, and to group it by the unique id from table1.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL's got the [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function for this, though it is internally limited to a default of 1024 characters, so you can't make arbitrarily large strings with it:

```
SELECT table1.id, CONCAT(table1.data, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.data))
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_ID
GROUP BY table1.id
```

If your string ends up being "large", you might be better off pulling the data in seperate queries and doing the concatenation in PHP.

Comment: Ok, I modified mine to have the column names instead of "*", and a group_concat on the column with the multiple values. It now concats the column I want. The issue now is it is only returning one result, instead of 2. Could it be because the 2nd set doesn't contain any data in the other 2 tables?

Comment: Yes, if there's no matching rows in table2, then you'll only get back to the table1.id field.

Comment: I need that value as well though.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a few certain columns, only select those columns (rather than `SELECT *`), and use `DISTINCT`. eg: `SELECT DISTINCT id, col, col FROM ...`

The `DISTINCT` keyword will make sure only unique rows are returned. If even one value is different, however, it's not unique and another row will be returned.